# CDN Converter - Scss to Css

Tags: sass, converters, cdn

i wonder if there is some CDN converter, which will convert my scss to css. I need to write some simple mockup project (SASS is required here) and don't want to prepare gulp or webpack for it. Also i have to avoide all websites like codepen etc.

Do you know something like this? Maybe there is something else, what will allow me using SASS files direct in my project.

Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you need is an Online Converter, if I correctly understood.
Take a look at sites like [Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) or online [SCSS](http://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php) or [SASS](http://beautifytools.com/sass-compiler.php) compilers.

If you don't want to depend in your connection, you can do this if you have ruby installed.

```
gem install sass
sass --update scss:css
```

Then your SCSS will be compiled CSS